# jquery: how to make a group of checkboxes fires a single event?

Tags: jquery, checkbox, checked

I have a group of checkboxes in a div and I use a check all/uncheck all function.

HTML:

```
<div id="available_options" class="input">
<ul class="inputs-list">
<li>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="options" id="option_1" />
    <span>Option1</span>
  </label>
</li>
<li>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="options" id="option_2" />
    <span>Option2</span>
  </label>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
<a id="check_all_options">Check all</a> / <a id="uncheck_all_options">Uncheck all</a>
```

Jquery:

```
 $('#check_all_options').click(function(e){
        $('#available_options input').attr('checked', 'checked').change();
});

$('#uncheck_all_options').click(function(e){
        $('#available_options input').removeAttr('checked').change();
});

$('#available_options input').live('change', function(e){
        alert('test');
});
```

At the moment my alert is fired whenever a checkbox is checked/unchecked which is good. However when using the "check all"/"uncheck all"  the alert is fired multiple times (each checkbox is firing an event). I have tried with stopPropagation but I can't get it to do what I want.

Any ideas how on can I get it to fire a single event every time a modification is made? I want to be able to get the options that are selected in order to launch a database query. But I do not want to launch the query multiple times when the checkall/uncheckall is used.

Thanks

Comment: I am confused. Why do you explicitly trigger `change` event? Simply calling your ajax/db query function from all 3 handlers would do it. http://jsfiddle.net/liho1eye/95f9Z/

Comment: hi your solution is what I wanted, if you propose it I can give you the credit. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reposting comment as answer:

Why do you explicitly trigger change event? Simply calling your ajax/db query function from all 3 handlers would do it. See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/liho1eye/95f9Z) for example.

Answer (score 2):

Shameless self-promotion: you might want to use [this jQuery plugin](https://github.com/mjball/jQuery-CheckAll) I wrote for this exact task. It would look something like this:

```
$('#check_all_options').checkAll('#available_options input[type="checkbox"]', {
    reportTo: function (numChecked) {
        console.log(numChecked);
    }
});
```

If you need more information in the `reportTo` callback beyond the number of boxes checked, I strongly encourage you to [submit an issue](https://github.com/mjball/jQuery-CheckAll/issues), and I can work on improving this little project!

---

If you don't want to use my plugin, that's cool too. You're still welcome to look at how it works, to understand how it fires only a single event for changes.

Comment: thanks for your help, your plugin looks good, however as I am bit rushed on this one I don't really have time to look into it so I will go with the solution proposed by  liho1eye

Answer (score 0):

You can see an example in this page:
http://briancray.com/2009/08/06/check-all-jquery-javascript/